# Apache POI Put an excel cell in bold

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

My question is simple: how to put a bold cell in an excel file?

I tried the 2 methods below but I always fall back on this error :

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.awt.Color"

1st method:

```
Font font = workbook.createFont();
font.setBold(true);

CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setFont(font);

Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
Cell cellID = row.getCell(0);
```

2nd method:

```
HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();

HSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
font.setBold(true);
style.setFont(font);
```

Comment: What JVM are you running this on? Could your install be corrupted?

Comment: @Gagravarr it's android so this class doesn't exist it's replaced by another

Answer (score 0):

AWT package is not available under android.
By the way, did you set your style on the cell you want to change?

Comment: i know that. I have try but i can't, i got this error when i create a custom fonts

Answer (score 0):

For Font setFont is not a function. You can use the following method though:

```
    font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
```

The same applies for HSSFFont. You can only use setFont function with XSSFFont.